# Latex: Text above mbox() when plotting horizontally?

Tags: image, latex

```
\begin{figure}[H]     
\centering
    \mbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{images/cor.pdf}}  
    \hspace{1px}
    \mbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.3]{images/co0re.pdf}}
    \hspace{1px}
    \mbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.3] {images/cooco.pdf}}
    \caption{Blah}
    \label{materialflowChart}
\end{figure}
```

I use the above to display 3 images side by side, horisontally.

It works, everything's good. But I'd like to add a small text above (or below) each subimage. Not a standard caption, but just a word like "A", "B", "C".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the use of sub figures already présented, there are many ways to do that:

1/ use minipages

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
\centering A\\  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1px}%
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
  \centering B\\  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{1px}%
\begin{minipage}{0.2\linewidth}
  \centering C\\  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Blah}
\label{materialflowChart}
\end{figure}
```

[image]
Note the I removed the useless \mbox{}, as \includegraphics already returns a TeX box.

Similarly, if you want to finely control the image spacing and really get 1px inter-image space, you must add '%' at end of lines to gobble the space and avoid the formatting by TeX.  This was also true in your original code.

2/ USe tabular

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{*{3}{@{\hspace{1px}}c}}
    A&B&C\\
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}&
    \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Blah}
  \label{materialflowChart}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Controlling column spacing is done with @{\hspace{1px}}. @ commands are inserted before the column and normal colum spacing is removed.

3/ use multicolumns with the multicol package

You can define in a minipage a box with several columns

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{0.7\linewidth}
    \setlength\columnsep{1px}
    \begin{multicols}{3}
      \centering A\\    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
      \columnbreak
      \centering B\\    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}\\
      \columnbreak
      \centering C\\    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \end{multicols}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Blah}
  \label{materialflowChart}
\end{figure}
```

\columnbreak starts a new column.
\columnsep is a length that controls the column spacing. Column width is computed with this parameter, the number of columns and width of the minipage.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using `mbox` for subfigures in not the right way to go. There are special packages for subfigure environments. For your special case I would suggest [`subcaption`](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    % The next line is necessary to omit automatic labeling a), b) c)
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}    
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{monalisa.jpg}
        \caption{A}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{monalisa.jpg}
        \caption{B}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{.3\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{monalisa.jpg}
        \caption{C}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{You can still use a global caption for the figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

gives exactly what you described: Three images horizontally with captions `A`, `B` and `C`. The line `\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}` purposely omits the automatic labeling of each image as `a)`, `b)` and `c)`.

[image]

However, your question sounds like you may want to use `A`, `B` and `C` as label to refer in the caption to it. In such case, remove the `\captionsetup...` line and the plot looks like this

[image]